# How to add remote start to backup generator?

Tags: generator, remote-control

I have a Briggs and Stratton 040248. I use it frequently in the winter since I live off grid. Is there a way to add a remote start?

Comment: Does it have a manual or automatic choke?

Comment: Do Briggs & Stratton supply a remote start kit? If not, what operations have to be automated?

Comment: You've asked two totally different questions: 1) "Is there a way?", and 2) "How do I?". Please [edit] your question to focus on one or the other. I'm pretty sure that you know the answer to 1) - there's _gotta_ be a way...

Comment: Did you read the title, @matt.? At this site, it's an expectation that the title question (and it is actually a question in this case) line up with the main question in the body.

Comment: @FreeMan You’re being unhelpfully pedantic. Most of us here are intelligent enough to read an implied “and if so how” after an “is it possible” question, without it being explicitly spelled out.

Comment: @SolarMike I can't find a remote start kit.

Comment: @crip659 automatic choke

Comment: So, what operations have to be automated?

Comment: @SolarMike I guess pressing and holding an on switch until it's on, the releasing. Similarly, holding off switch until it's off. They are the same switch with differing directions for each function.

Comment: So no ignition circuit to turn on? That’s good. How would you check for a success on start? Or fail?

Comment: @SolarMike I'd probably just listen for success and release the button I was holding I imagine.

Comment: So if you are close enough to listen then you don't need remote. I took remote to be 50 or 5000 miles away...

Comment: @SolarMike nope, more like 50ft.